# How do I run a python script, from a batch file, that acts as a subprocess of the cmd instance?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess

I'm trying to use a batch file to run a python script so that when the batch session ends (termination for example) the python script will also close.

For example, if I wanted to do the reverse thing (Python->batch). I would use subprocess module.

How can I achieve this?

this is the relevant line in the batch file:

```
python run.py %*
```

Which runs the python script, but upon terminating it, the python script keeps running

Comment: If you already have the line in the batch file, whats the issue? Is the batch file terminating before the python script has finished?

Comment: I want to terminate the batch file before the python script, but I also want that action to terminate the pythin script, which is not the case.

Comment: That doesnt make any sense at all, why does the batch file need to terminate first? Could you do something like run the python script in the background and then at the end of your batch script have a callback command to kill all subprocesses of the current script?

Comment: The actual batch file is running as a part of a bigger script/program. When the main script/program ends it's job, it needs to terminate everything still running. It can terminate the batch but not the python script the batch has started. This information is irrelevant for the solution, if there ia one, so I didnt include the fine details of the task in my question.

Comment: Why dont you just call taskkill on the Python script at the end of your .bat ? If the python process exists: kill the process; end .bat

Comment: Unless the Python script has a window (not a console window unless it's the nominal console owner), taskkill will require the /F option to forcibly terminate the process, which is crude. I'd write another Python script that uses subprocess to run the main script. If it's a console process, use the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` creation flag. Then have the watchdog open a handle to the CMD shell parent and wait on it. When CMD exits, the handle will be signaled. Then you can send the main Python script a Ctrl+Break. If it's written well, it handles `SIGBREAK` to exit gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Shell script should be like this to execute run.py :
`python run.py`

If you want to include command line arguments for run.py your shell script will be like:
`python run.py %1 %2`
where `%1` and `%2` are the command line arguments.

Your batch script can't end unless python file is fully executed. Make sure you had done all things correctly.